# Conditional element in class constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know that in javascript we can add an conditional parameter for object like this:

```js
const a = {
   ...(someCondition && {b: 5})
}
```

Is there a possibility to do something like that in classes and to hide `width` depends if it is passed or not as above?:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width; // this should be conditional
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t need to be fancy. Just use an `if` statement: `if(width !== undefined){ this.width = width; }`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? For it to also work for a square without needing to pass the same value twice, just do `this.width = width ?? height;`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Genuine question, what would be the profit of doing width != undefined instead of just if(width) because anything with 0 width will be nonexistent

Comment: @ArnavMishra `if(arg !== undefined)` is the idiomatic way to check for arguments that weren’t passed. _“because anything with 0 width will be nonexistent”_ — That depends on the implementation.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I had a question about stack overflow ettiqutes. if someone answers the question in commands am i not supposed to write an answer for i?

Comment: Btw, @AskMen, don't do this. Having optional properties in your class, and thereby instances of different shapes, degrades performance. Consider using `this.width = width || undefined;` instead if you need to have a special "absence" value.

Comment: @ArnavMishra Usually, a possible “answer” is hinted at in comments under off-topic or duplicate questions which are then quickly closed, but in this case, me saying that an `if` statement should be used was just a _suggestion_, not necessarily an answer. I don’t know all the requirements of the OP; so the OP could accept or reject this idea, and only then I’d be confident in a possible answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use anything complex to achieve this. An if statement would suffice for a situation like this.

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    if (width) this.width = width; // this should be conditional
    console.log(this)
  }
}
new Rectangle(1)
```

This would work completely fine in javascript^^